# Modified by Community

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

What does it mean that a question was "Modified by Community"?

---

[image: Modified]

---

Answer (score 4):

In the current case it said so as a [suggested edit by somebody that has no account took effect](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5233).

Even without an account one can suggest edits, if this edit is approved there is no user-account to which it could be assigned, and thus it is assigned to the [Community-user](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Similarly, it would say this if the modifying action was taken by an account that afterwards got deleted (at the time of writing you can see an example for this on this meta with the question [Who is MESE for, exactly?](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/who-is-mese-for-exactly); to see it in that case, look for it in the list of question, it is currently the third, on the question-thread itself it is not visible).

Another reason for "modified by Community" is when the post gets automatically "bumped" to give it renewed visibility while no actual action happened.

Comment: Thank, quid. I see now that the edit was to an answer, not my question. I misinterpreted the meaning of "modified," which I now see means that some aspect of the posting---question or one of the answers---was modified.

Comment: You are welcome. I believe under certain circumstances "modified" can even mean the addition of a new answer (though this is often indicated as "answered," and I am not quite sure about the rules that govern this).